# How do I access the Vector2 value of the touchpad from a Vive remote using Steam VR in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, htc-vive, steamvr

I’m trying to access the Vector2 value from the remote, but I have no idea what the syntax is to do so and I couldnt find anything online about it.

```
 private SteamVR_Input_Sources inputSource = SteamVR_Input_Sources.Any;
    public SteamVR_Action_Vector2 touchpadAction;
    private void Update()
    {
        if (touchpadAction.GetChanged(inputSource)) {
            Vector2 touchpadAxis = touchpadAction.GetAxis(inputSource);
            Debug.Log("touchpad");
        }
```

This is my code. I also made sure to add adjustInput for the touchpadAction field in the inspector window as shown below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ83v.png)

These are my bindings for the controls. I called the touchpad position input "AdjustInput"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdz8Z.png)